# c++ allocating objects?

Tags: c++

in c++ if I created object thru heap it means it is created at runtime.
if I created object not using new keyword it is created at compile time.

is it okay if I hear the word heap it means runtime?

2nd question

in java if a reference to an object refers to a different object then the object it first refers will get destroyed automatically by garbage collector because no one refers to it.
is same thing happen in c++ like if you create an object along heap, then make a pointer to it, then assign a pointer to that object. 
If that pointer points to a different object what will happen to the object in the heap is this object will destroyed by executing destructor automatically?

Comment: Not really, no.  The app cannot create objects at compile time because it is not running, (or even existing).  C++ if you overwrite the last/only poiinter to an object, the object is leaked, not destroyed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Local objects are created on the stack at runtime, and do not involve the use of new

Objects created with new are not destroyed until someone calls delete on them

Static objects are created at program startup.

Comment: what is static memory allocationg?? is that compile time?? so you cant create an object at compile time??

Comment: The word "compile" means _translate a program into machine language_.  it's got nothing to do with memory allocation or creating objects. It's analogously equivalent to taking a text book and translating the content into a foreign language.